# Регулярные выражения: исключить буквы и оставить некоторые символы PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, которое проверяет строку на то, чтобы в ней были только цифры(от 7 до 15), но также среди цифр могли бы быть символы "-", "(", ")", " "(пробел). Причем пробелов и символов "-" было не больше 5, а каждой из скобочек не больше 1.
Например 053654895665, или 96(8) 956-17-26

Comment: валидация телефона это дно, так как в америке и других странах могут быть телефоны с буквами, это сравнимо с валидацией имени и фамилии, не понимаю почему заказчики думают что человек не в состояние написать свои фио это обсурд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Например 053654895665, или 96(8) 956-17-26*

Для вашего примера подойдёт такой вариант:

```
$str = 'Например 053654895665, или 96(8) 956-17-26';

preg_match_all('~\b(?:\d{7,15}|\d{2}\(\d\)\s?\d{3}(?:-\d{2}){2})\b~', $str, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

---

**UPD:** Вариант с учётом списка номеров:

```
$str = '+375296398545
+375(29)6398545
375296398545
375-29-639-85-45
+375-29-639-85-45
+375(29)639-85-45
375(29)639-85-45
375(29)639 85 45
+375 29 639 85 45
375 29 6398545';

$patt = '~
    \b \+? (?:

        # +375296398545 или 375296398545
        \d{7,15}     |

        # +375(29)6398545
        \d{3}  \( \d{2} \)  \d{7}     |

        # 375-29-639-85-45
        (?:  \d{3}- \d{2}-  ){2}  \d{2}     |

        # +375(29)639-85-45 и все остальные
        \d{3}  [\h(] \d{2} [\h)]  \d{3}  (?:  [\h-]? \d{2}  ){2}

    )\b
~x';

preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Результат *(все номера из списка)*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 375296398545
            [1] => 375(29)6398545
            [2] => 375296398545
            [3] => 375-29-639-85-45
            [4] => 375-29-639-85-45
            [5] => 375(29)639-85-45
            [6] => 375(29)639-85-45
            [7] => 375(29)639 85 45
            [8] => 375 29 639 85 45
            [9] => 375 29 6398545
        )
)
```

> P.S.: Всё не предусмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Валидация телефона это дно, так как в Америке и других странах могут быть телефоны с буквами, это сравнимо с валидацией имени и фамилии. Не понимаю почему заказчики думают, что человек не в состоянии написать свои ФИО, это абсурд.

Ну, как алгоритм, могу предложить следующее:

```
// удалим разрешенные символы из строки
$phoneCheck = str_replace(['+', ' ', ')', '(', '-'], '', $phone);
// далее приводим к integer
$phoneCheckSumm = (int) $phoneCheck;
// сравниваем две переменные 
if($phoneCheck == $phoneCheckSumm && $phoneCheck >= 7 && $phoneCheck <= 15) {
   echo 'все верно';
} else {
   echo 'что то не так';
}
```

Логика проста, если при проведение к типу integer php отсечет буквы, либо символы, то переменные не будут равны.
В общем лучше не валидировать такие вещи, ибо это создаст больше неудобства чем пользы для пользователя

**p.s.** 15 это не цифра, а число, так что задача неверна.